# Create link in cart sidebar to view all added items After limit reached

Tags: magento-1.8, cart, shopping-cart

I have set my cart sidebar to show only 2 items that have been added to the basket through the admin panel, what I want to be able to do is create a link if more than 2 items have been added, so if a user added say 5 products the cart sidebar would display 2 items as normal and a link saying "view all 5 products in basket". I don't want the link to be visible if there are 2 or less items in the basket.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php $itemsCount = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->getItemsCount();?>
<?php if ($itemsCount > 2) : ?>
    <a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkout/cart')?>"><?php echo $this->__('view all items')?></a>
<?php endif;?>
```